# Laravel view from different folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-views

I have a laravel project where I have the following view:

```
'ProjectName\custom\subfolder\resources\views\theview.blade.php'
```

How can I return this view?

I tried to use **view('theview')** That did not work because that only works on views inside:

```
 'ProjectName\resources\views'
```

How can I return the view from outside theresources\views folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside the `config/view.php` config file, add to the `paths` key:

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => [
        realpath(base_path('resources/views')),
        realpath(base_path('custom/subfolder/resources/views')),
    ],


    'compiled' => realpath(storage_path('framework/views')),

];
```

You can load your views in the usual way, eg `view('my-view')`, however duplicate names (or name collisions) will result in Laravel selecting the view based on the order specified in the `paths` key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, How should I then call the view?

Comment: Yes using `view('theview')` should work, how exactly is it not working?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely spot on! Just in the Laravel 6.0

```
'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
        resource_path('views/canaanmodels'),
    ],
```

Where my view is in the folder **'canaanmodels'** which is inside **'views'** floder and the **realpath** has now been replaced with **resource_path** and there is no more **base_path**... Hope it gonna help someone! Cheers

Comment: `base_path` is still a thing: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-base-path